# CSS / R shiny: removing padding below navbar

Tags: html, css, r, twitter-bootstrap, shiny

I'm working on a [shiny app](https://latimerlab.shinyapps.io/reforestation-tool/) but have very little web development expertise. I'm wondering what CSS element/class I need to modify to remove the white space between the top navigation bar and the rest of the page (indicated by the red arrow below).

I used the document explorer (F12) in my browser, and it seems that section is called `navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top` so I tried adding the following CSS to the page:

`.navbar .navbar-default .navbar-static-top {padding: 0px; !important}`

But it had no effect. I've gotten other CSS to work for my app (e.g., background color), but this one is stubborn. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Try `margin` with some negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `margin-bottom` that is being applied from the nav, setting it to zero solved the problem for me as you can see on the screenshot. (Sharing your site was very helpful to troubleshoot)

```
.navbar .navbar-default .navbar-static-top {margin-bottom: 0px}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution-

Setting the margin-bottom of .navbar .navbar-default .navbar-static-top to 0 works.

Cheers